# Error using spatial.median from package ICSNP (R)

Tags: r, coordinates, median

I have several coordinates and I want the geometric median of those coordinates. I'm using the function spatial.median from the package ICSNP. Sometimes it works, but sometime it doesn't.

```
     latitude     longitude
[1,] -20.35808333 -40.29396500
[2,] -20.35808333 -40.29396500
[3,] -20.35810666 -40.29414666
```

If i try this data.frame, it returns the error:

> Error in array(STATS, dims[perm]) : 'dims' cannot be of length 0

If I change to

```
      latitude     longitude
 [1,] -20.35808334 -40.29396500
 [2,] -20.35808333 -40.29396500
 [3,] -20.35810666 -40.29414666
```

or

```
     latitude     longitude
[1,] -20.35808333 -40.29396500
[2,] -20.35808333 -40.29396500
[3,] -20.35810666 -40.29414666
[3,] -20.35812336 -40.29434526
```

it works fine.

I know that if all coordinates were equal, it would give another error that I already have treated. I don't know how to treat this.